# How to make restrictions to the CNN kernel in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, kernel, conv-neural-network

Our specific training problem requires that all the weights in a CNN kernel must be positive. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why must they be kept positive?

Comment: Because those weights have physical meanings in our problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for kernel constraints, this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694368/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-weight-constraints-in-tensorflow) has the answer to your question. 
You can either use kernel constraints or simply adopt the lagrange optimization technique to add a term to your overall loss function that removes the feature of the weights that you don't need. Something like this (as it is mentioned in the referenced answer),

```py
added_loss = -tf.minimum(tf.reduce_min(theta),0)
final_loss = your_loss + added_loss
optimizer.minimize(final_loss)
```

It is also necessary to note that, adding this loss only encourages the optimization to look for a solution which has theta or as you say weights to be all positive, there is no guarantee that the best fit parameters are all positive. To ensure such a behaviour, you can clip the weights between 
0 and +infinity.

Comment: What if we just require some of the weights to be positive. Is it still possible?

Comment: If you need some of the weights to be positive, then you can use a mask that zeros out the weights that has no constraints and keeps the one you want to impose a constraint on. E.g, taking the hamdard product of the weight kernel with a matrix of same shape with 0 element at position where you want to have no constraints and 1 where you want to have the constraint and then use the resulting matrix, i.e inplace of ```tf.reduce_min(theta)``` you do ```tf.reduce_min(masked_theta)```.

Comment: Note that if you dont know which weights to be imposed a constraint on, just simply do the langrage technique. It will get you the best solution possible with maximum number of positive weights in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Another question is that, can we still do the same thing if we use tf.layer.conv2D instead of defining our own kernel variable?

Comment: Defining your own kernel and using it for convolution layer is the best way to have full freedom for applying and experimenting with different techniques. After having your kernel, you can use ```tf.nn.conv2D``` for using your kernal for convolution. More can be found on the documentation.

Comment: If the answer helped you, kindly upvote and mark as approved  answer. Thank you so much.